# MySQL query - find name of beverages with both size

Tags: mysql

I have a table called beverages. It has the attributes name, id, and size.

How would I make a query that finds all the drinks with both size "maxi" and size "medium"

In other words. I have to find the beverages with the same name that have both sizes, as each tuple can only have one size.

Comment: Howdy....before anything else you may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  then, come back to your answer and provide some details like your table structure and the query you are trying that's not working for you.  With that you should get some help.  It's difficult to give a good answer to your question as it is.  An example of your table and data in something like http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be a bonus good thing to include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE beverages 
 (id INT, 
  NAME VARCHAR(50), 
  size VARCHAR(50));
```

And a sample data like this:

| id | name | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | orange | medium |
| 1 | orange | medium |
| 1 | orange | maxi |
| 1 | orange | maxi |
| 2 | soda | medium |
| 3 | cola | maxi |
| 4 | lemon tea | medium |
| 5 | soy milk | medium |
| 5 | soy milk | medium |
| 5 | soy milk | medium |
| 5 | soy milk | maxi |
| 5 | soy milk | maxi |
| 6 | coffee | maxi |
| 7 | chocolate | maxi |

And you want to find any drinks that have both size so you do a query like:

```
SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT size), COUNT(DISTINCT size) 
FROM beverages 
GROUP BY id, name
```

Whereby this query returns:

| id | name | group_concat(size) | count(*) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | orange | medium,maxi | 2 |
| 2 | soda | medium | 1 |
| 3 | cola | maxi | 1 |
| 4 | lemon tea | medium | 1 |
| 5 | soy milk | medium,maxi | 2 |
| 6 | coffee | maxi | 1 |
| 7 | chocolate | maxi | 1 |

Now you found drinks where their `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT size)` return more than one result and `COUNT(DISTINCT size)` return two.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac113b6f7f8fb7fdeced327e94db888e)

Comment: Hmm, what if i specifically only want the names of the drinks that can be found in medium and maxi (and other sizes, but we only care about medium and maxi ). Like fx. how would you only return Soy Milk and Orange, since they have both those sizes

Comment: P/S: I posted this in hopes that you would understand it's easier for people to help you if you provide at least such detail in the first place. Anyway, if you [look at the fiddle I've provided](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac113b6f7f8fb7fdeced327e94db888e) , on the 5th box; where there's a query with `having count(*) =1`, you can change to `having count(*) =2` to get any drinks with 2 counts.